# Does the closure of bounded above subset of reals includes both infinimum and supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

As far as I know, let  $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ which is bounded above, then $\operatorname{cl}(S)$ includes $\sup(S)$. Also, if $S$ is bounded below, then $\inf(S) \in \operatorname{cl}(S)$. But, does $\inf(S) \in \operatorname{cl}(S)$ when $S$ has bounded above? How do you prove that? I suppose the answer is no, but I could not construct any proof.

Comment: $inf S$ can be $-\infty$ (as in the case $S=(-\infty, 0)$) so it need not belong to $cl(S)$. But if $S$ is also bounded below then the result is true.

Comment: If $S$ is only bounded from above but *not* bounded from below, then $\inf(S)$ does not exist. If it *is* bounded from below, then $\inf S\in \text{cl}(S)$ - but you've already known that!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy question only states that it is bounded above, so I can assume that it is not bounded below. Is it just enough to say that inf(S) does not exist?

Comment: You  cannot say 'does not exist''. You can say 'need not exist'.

Comment: In my opinion, it really doesn't make sense to ask whether $\inf S\in\text{cl}S$ when $\inf S$ does not exist. It is indeed true that when the infimum or supremum exist, they lie in the closure. Note that existence of infimum in reals implies bounded below.

Comment: @mathrookie: "question only states..." Would you mind sharing the *actual* question you are trying to solve? Also, the following is *not* equivalent: (1) "question does not say if $S$ is bounded..."; (2) "question says that $S$ is not bounded..."

Comment: @StinkingBishop Statement is "Let α = inf S and β = sup S for some subset S of R. Suppose that S is bounded from above. "

Comment: "Suppose that S is bounded from above.". Then what? What do you have to prove?

Comment: @StinkingBishop prove or disprove that infS is in clS and supS is in clS

Comment: Very strange wording indeed. They don't assume $S$ is bounded from below, i.e. they don't assume that $\inf S$ exists, but they nevertheless give it a name $\alpha$. My *guess* is that they allow $\alpha$ to have the value $-\infty$ (when it doesn't exist), and then: if $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ then $\alpha\in\text{cl}(S)$; if $\alpha=-\infty$ then, obviously $\alpha\not\in\text{cl}(S)$. Also "prove or disprove" - you cannot either prove it or disprove it because for some $S$ it is true and for some $S$ it is false... You can only point to examples where it's true and where it isn't.